# glBindFramebuffer not defined?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have reinstalled Code::Blocks and GLFW3 after finally growing tired of not being able to experiment and do stuff in c++ on my pc for about one or two months, I got far enough to where I am trying to make a simple window that gets cleared. The problem is that the window doesn't get cleared at all except for pitch black darkness. At first I thought it might be because I use a function to draw the window, but that wasn't the issue either. I tried adding `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);` before the clear to see if that would fix the issue, but then the compiler said that glBindFramebuffer wasn't declared.

Here's main.cpp

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void loop(GLFWwindow* window,bool &quit);

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR,4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR,5);

    GLFWwindow* window=glfwCreateWindow(512,512,"Test",NULL,NULL);

    glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    bool quit=false;
    do
    {
        loop(window,quit);
    }while(quit==false);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

And loop.cpp

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void loop(GLFWwindow* window,bool &quit){
    glfwPollEvents();

    if(glfwGetKey(window,GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)==GLFW_PRESS)
        quit=true;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0); <-Error here
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

EDIT: So after figuring out I need to load functions I've tried GLEW to no avail, GL3W doesn't seem to work in linux and all other options seems to be too god damned advanced for what it is and won't work in anyways.

Comment: Framebuffers were added in GL 3. To use any function that is not part of GL 1 or 2 you need to *load* that function. Doing this manually may be hard, so most programmers use external libraries for this. For example, GLEW: http://glew.sourceforge.net/ A single call to `glewInit()` will load all needed functions and then you can use then normally (they're a part of glew header).

Comment: Thanks, strange that isn't mentioned in the documentation. Now I only have to figure out why it seg errors

Comment: @MetroidChild: "*strange that isn't mentioned in the documentation*" The documentation of what? [OpenGL function loading](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) is a well-known part of building any OpenGL application. There are [entire libraries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that exist to do that, and I would most certainly *not* suggest GLEW.

Comment: in the documentation of functions in the doc pages it should say that the functions have to be used through outside programs, why make things harder for the beginner? even though I've used opengl for over two years this still comes off as strange

Comment: @NicolBolas What's wrong with GLEW?

Comment: No proper support for opengl 3.2+ it seems, also getting opengl loader generator working was easy enough. BUT I still won't get anything but a black screen whatever I do

Comment: @MetroidChild: The whole OpenGL loading business has been well documented for a looong time. Also extension loading is not an external program, but part of your own program, either incorporated through a library or by your very own code.